# Правильная сетка на bootstrap

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap

Вот два варианта одной и той же верстки. Выглядят одинаково но подход к ним разный. Берут сомнения что какой то из них не правильный. Вопрос: какой из этих вариантов правильный?

№1:

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="border:1px solid black;">Шапка сайта</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid black;">Левый блок</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="border:1px solid black;">Основной блок</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="border:1px solid black;">Подвал сайта</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

№2:

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="border:1px solid black;">Шапка сайта</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid black;">Левый блок</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="border:1px solid black;">Основной блок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="border:1px solid black;">Подвал сайта</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Визуально второй проще воспринимать и меньше шансов запутаться

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но как правило подход к таким проблемам сугубо утилитарный, то есть что удобнее использовать для нужного эффекта то и используется.
И чисто визуально и интуитивно я бы использовал вариант два так как он более читабельный

Comment: я так же рассуждаю. но довольно авторитетный сайт первый вариант считает правильным. второй это мой. вот и сомневаюсь

Comment: а что на авторитетном сайте приводится в качестве аргумента? мне например вообще в любых условиях претит использовать конструкции типа   <div class="clearfix"></div>

Comment: вот здесь учат правильной верске https://itchief.ru/lessons/bootstrap-3/108-bootstrap-3-main-elements-for-meshing . статьи довольно грамотно написаны. подробнее пока нигде не видел.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, что бы не путаться код комментировать надо.

Comment: @perfect, код надо комментировать, а вот разметку лучше читать визуально, в первом варианте нет глубины, из-за чего коментируй не комментируй визуально хуже читается. Использовать комментарии в html я вообще бредом считаю.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, я не привязываюсь. комментарии дело добровольное. но разве разметка это не код?

Comment: @perfect, да, оказывается разметка тоже код. В голове всё равно мысль что код это нечто исполняемое. На вашем месте я усомнился бы в авторитетности ресурса, который вы указали и посмотрел бы как делают тут - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev и там то же самое написано http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Comment: @perfect, совсем не то же самое. В этом примере они ставят `clearfix` только для `xs` когда надо отбить только в мелкой версии. В вашей разметке правилен второй вариант, все жестко отбивается `.row`.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev тогда буду на это наедятся, если никто не переубедит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При условии, что вы не указываете для `.row` и `.col` отличные от нуля `margin` и `padding` (а указывать их, к слову, не следует никогда) - внешне оба варианта будут выглядеть одинаково.

Мало того, в первом варианте вы можете даже не использовать блок `.clearfix`. Потому что `.col-sm-4` и `.col-sm-8` и так займут всю ширину экрана, и следующий `.col`, каким бы он ни был - гарантированно будет перенесен на следующую строку.

Какой из вариантов выбрать - зависит от ситуации.

Первый вариант лучше подходит тогда, когда содержимое сетки строится вами динамически. Например, когда вы можете взять записи из БД, и последовательно, в цикле, выводить их в `.col`-блоках в верстке. Блоки просто будут переноситься на следующие строки при необходимости. При условии, что блоки одной строки в сумме будут давать 12, и при условии, что высоты содержимого колонов будут одинаковы.

Второй вариант лучше подходит, когда все блоки в сетке заранее вам известны. За счет `.row` вы ограждаете колонки разных строк друг от друга, читабельность при таком способе - выше.

Comment: `clearfix` нужен не только для принудительного переноса, но и чтобы разные по высоте колонки [не цеплялись друг за друга](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets). Блок в 12 колонок никакими выступами не задержать, он сам себе `clearfix`. А блок на 8 (или меньше) колонок может зацепиться.